# Representation of Functionals of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to solve the following exercise: let $V$ be the space of polynomials with real coefficients of degree at most $2$ and indeterminate $x$. Let $\langle p,q \rangle:=\int_{-1}^1 p(x)q(x)dx$ be the inner product defined on $V$ and let $F \in V^*$ so defined: $F(p(x)):=2p'(0)$. Which is the unique polynomial $q(x) \in V$ such that $F(p(x))=\langle q,p\rangle$ for any $p(x) \in V$?

I have no clue. Can you help me, please?

Comment: You know $q$ exists. Call it $q(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ and test the value of $F(p(x))$ for some easy polynomials, like $p = x^i$ for $ = 0, 1, 2$. This will give you relations for the unknown coeficients.

Comment: I presume that $F(p(x))$ is supposed to be defined as $2p'(0)$, since $f$ appears nowhere else in your question. You might first try to figure out what $F(p(x))$ is for the general quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$.